# How to Cheat Android at checking Connectivity?

Tags: android, network-programming, tun

I'm doing a network App using tun as virtual network device on Android. I close other available interfaces such as eth0 (for WLAN) and rmnet0 (for 3G/GPRS) but keep my tun0 device alive and add a rule in route table

`ip route add default dev tun0`

so I can redirect all internet transfer into tun device (what I'm doing here is the same as OpenVPN). And then I saw the data transferring when I ping other IP. Browser and some other Apps work fine.

But some of Android Apps will check the Connectivity by ConnectivityManager before accessing netwrok. Since I close WIFI & 3G/GPRS, ConnectivityManager considers there is no connection, those Apps won't access network anymore.

So my question is:

How to **CHEAT** android ConnectiviyManager, make it believe that there is still an available connection (for any type)?

Comment: No. seems there is no way to do that. So I just simply close it?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's intended to work that way

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, and you wouldn't want to, it's a system-wide service. Imagine if your app relied on internet connectivity, but some malicious app was able to tell you there was and make your app unable to complete it's actions. It could cause a serious problem.

If your app needs to believe there is a connection in some states, I suggest you interface the connectivity / network classes, you can read the true state but then return whichever value you deem fit to your app

Comment: my app can uses my new network connection without problem, but other app cannot.